# jvmti for jdk 6 - references and tutorials

Tags: java, jvmti, javaagents

Does anyone know a good starting point to learn writing jvmti agents.

I am looking for books or online tutorials for this.

I looked at the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html

But it does not seem to provide a clear outline of the how-to.

Any references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this one (java.sun.com)](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jvmti/) a couple of years back, it seems to still be there. You probably need to understand what is in the platform docs (your link) as well.